# MySQL "GROUP BY" experiment

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I am testing SQL and I am stuck on one query. It is a useless query but I want to understand it.

```
select count(*), floor(rand()*2) as x from table_name group by x;
```

The result is either two rows, or `duplicate entry '0/1' for key 'group_key'`

What happens that leads to this error?

Comment: Learn how to use `GROUP BY`.  It's not even a valid `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

rand() is going to generate a random number for every row in your table. You are then grouping by the results of all of those random numbers. You will get one row for each unique value.

Comment: but doing floor(rand()*2) only 0 and 1 can be generated for each row

Answer (score 0):

The main point here is not to group by some strange sinthetic data.
Better to group by some certain fields.
Because mysql have some bugs there.

Like this
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=58081

Or this
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=60808

Certainly it is trying to create a unique index on a tmp table and that is somehow not working